# Why is local wordpress install calling live site executions?

Tags: mysql, localhost, apache

I recently installed Apache/MySQL/phpMyAdmin  and WordPress on my mac so I could have a dev environment for my live wordpress site. Shortly after installing and setting up a local version of my live site, I received a notification from my hosting company, Siteground, that my live site had too many site executions in the last 24 hours.

The data on Siteground(IP address, time of executions) suggested my machine and, most likely, my recent install was to blame. After turning off the stack, the problem abated. Yesterday, after weeks of having no issues, I got brave and turned everything on to test some site changes I wanted to implement. By the end of the day, my Siteground account said once again I had exceeded the maximum number allowed daily executions.

By all appearances, it looks like every time I turn on localhost (Apache/MySQL) it’s somehow causing executions on my live site.

Admittedly, I’m not a professional stack/web developer, and I could have misconfigured something. Would anyone have any suggestions as to how to go about resolving this issue?

Thank you!

Comment: I would guess that you've used your live site URL for the dev site, or have the live hostname hard coded into the theme somewhere.

Comment: @AndyMacaulay-Brook -- Thank you for the reply! I've made many changes structural/design changes to the localhost site with no effect on the live site. All permalinks were changed to reflect my local environment. Everything in my config.php file seems fine, too.  Would you be able to clarify a little more about what you mean and where I could check?

Comment: View source on a page in your browser and search for the live hostname to see what comes up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't thorough enough initially. Old wp-config.php files were found in my downloads folder. It looked like these files came from the zip file Duplicator created when copying my live site. These files contained config information to my live site database. After deleting them, the problem has gone away.